# Gerusha who marries a Kohen

Tags: sources-mekorot, kohen-priest, mourning-aveilus, shulchan-aruch, divorce

I’m currently learning the Halachos of Aveilus with a Chavrusah and we discussed the following question if a gerusha who marries a Kohen and he dies, does she sit shiva and observe the mourning period 30days etc.

Comment: [Seems not](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.374.4?lang=bi#:~:text=%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%9A%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%90)

Comment: [See also](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99:%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A:%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%93_%D7%93#.D7.9E.D7.A1.D7.9B.D7.AA_.D7.A9.D7.9E.D7.97.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.A7_.D7.93_.D7.94.D7.9C.D7.9B.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.92-.D7.93)